# How to fix .default.ref is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have an issue uploading an image for firebase storage.

This is my firebase config file

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage'
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/auth';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'apiKey',
    authDomain: 'authDomain',
    databaseURL: 'databaseURL',
    projectId: 'projectId',
    storageBucket: 'storageBucket',
    messagingSenderId: 'messagingSenderId',
    appId: 'appId'
};

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const storage = firebase.storage();

export {
    storage ,fire as default
}
```

I import it as storage in my Component and use it as

```
storage.ref('images/' + this.state.imageUrl.name).put(this.state.imageUrl).on(
    'state_changed',
    (snapshot) => {},
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
        storage.ref('images').child(this.state.imageUrl.name).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            console.log(url);
        });
    }
)
```

But whenever I click a button it throws me this error

> 'TypeError: _config_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.default.ref is not a function'

Comment: `export default {
    storage ,fire
}` should work.

Comment: My app breaks then. Fire works perfectly fine, but storage is not working at all

Comment: how do you import it inside your component ?

Comment: import fire from '../../config/config';
import storage from '../../config/config';
I've tried import * as firebase from '../../config/config;
and then using it as firebase.fire or firebase.storage but that didn't work, I get 'fire is not exported as default from config'

Comment: That won't work since you use default export.
`import config from '../../config/config'` should work, and then you access it by `config.fire` and `config.storage`

Comment: you should write `import {storage} from '...'` instead of `import storage from '...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when writing `export {storage ,fire as default}`, it means you are exporting `storage` as a named export and `fire` as a default export, its equivalent as the following code

```
export const storage = firebase.storage();
export default firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

To solve your problem you need to fix the imports in your component

```
import {storage, default as fire} from 'config';
```

or

```
import {storage} from 'config';
import fire from 'config';
```